# Division of a polynomial by a monomial

Tags: polynomials

I am trying to divide this polynomial by 2x ...

$$
(4x^6 - 3x^3 + 2x + 1) / 2x
$$

Here's what I'm trying to do (divide all monomial by 2x) :
$$
(4x^6 / 2x) - (3x^3 / 2x) + (2x / 2x) + (1 / 2x)
$$

Then, I obtain: $$ 2x^5 - 3x^2 + 1 + (1/2x) $$

I'm trying to validate my answer with Wolfram bit it doesn't work..

Comment: Seems to work: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284x^6+-+3x^3+%2B+2x+%2B+1%29+%2F+2x). (plus, you'll have $\frac{3x^2}{2}$ instead of $3x^2$). In alpha, scroll down to alternative forms.

Comment: I'm going to delete the "monoidal-categories" tag. I suspect the OP started typing "monomial", mistyped, and/or accepted the wrong "suggestion".

Comment: @kuch Perhaps you should write you comment out as an answer so that this becomes answered.

Comment: @mixedmath done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284x6%20-%203x3%20%2b%202x%20%2b%201%29%20/%202x) , scroll down to the section titled alternate forms.